# Access location of a button in GridLayout

Tags: java

I have a grid of buttons and i want to know if theres a way to retrieve the location of the button pressed, i have an action listener for the buttons but i need the Row and column of the button that was pressed and i cant seem to figure out how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
JButton.setActionCommand(String actionCommand)
```

to associate any information you want with the button, so you can encode some value that specifies the information you want there.

Then when you get your actionListener called, you can retrieve it thru

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    String cmd = ae.getActionCommand();
    //based on cmd, do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One relatively easy way is to put the buttons in a 2D array and then iterate through the array with a pair of nested for loops til you find the button that matches the current (via ActionEvent#getSource().  Then your row and column are the loop indices.